# Python: how to draw a normal line to a 2D curve?

Tags: python

I have the x,y coordinates of a curve

x = [x1, x2, ..., xn]

y = [y1, y2, ..., yn]

I want to draw a normal line which passes [xk, yk], where xk, yk is coordinate of the k-th point on my curve.

How to realize it in Python?

Comment: How do you define a "normal line" through a *vertex* of a polygon? Normal lines are defined at differentiable points in a curve, but a vertex is (almost always) not differentiable. You call it a curve, but if it is defined by finitely many points on it, it is a polygon. Unless, of course, you mean something different, but you need to say what that is.

Comment: Looks like a perfectly valid question.  Given a set of points from y = f(x), determine the first derivative at point f(x[k) and find the normal line.  You might be get a better answer if you tag the question scipy.

Comment: What kind of "curve" do the points represent?

Answer (score -1):

[Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) is the most common library for plotting in python.

A small example to get you started:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [5,6,9,13]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all. I've solved the problem.

First I do a spline, then calculated the differential function and find the tangent slope k using the given point [xk, yk]. The slope of the normal like is -1/k. In the end, the normal line is plotted.

Comment: Could you explain in detail